# Override the implementation of a base class such that calls from inherited base class functions also call the overidden function

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

I have to override a function in a base class in such a way that calls to inherited functions also lead to calls to this overridden function instead of the base implementation.

```
class base_class
{
    string abc;
    public int get_1()
    {
        return 1;
    }
    public  int get_number()
    {
        return get_1()+1;
    }
}

class der_class : base_class
{
    public int get_1()
    {
        return 2;
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        der_class abc = new der_class();
        Console.WriteLine(abc.get_number());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

This prints 2. How can I get the output to be 3 by making the get_number to call overridden get_1?

Comment: If it's c# and not c++, the method in the base class should be marked as `virtual` and the method in the derived class should be marked as `overrides`

Comment: If you want to override a method then you have to actually override it, which requires the keywords mentioned by @ZoharPeled. The code you posted should have generated a warning telling you that your method hides an inherited member, which is not the same as overriding.

Answer (score 5):

You need the `override` keyword to actually override a method, otherwise you are hiding it.

```
class der_class : base_class
{
    // note the word override here!
    public override int get_1()
    {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Also, you need to make the method `virtual` in the base class:

```
class base_class
{
    string abc;
    // note the word virtual here!
    public virtual int get_1()
    {
        return 1;
    }
    public  int get_number()
    {
        return get_1()+1;
    }
}
```